# Enable flash in GeckoView(Firefox) on Android 4.4

Tags: android, firefox, mozilla, gecko, fennec

Recently I found an interesting thing is that Flash still works on firefox android 4.4 and there actually an firefox view(geckoView) that we can replace the webview. 
I followed the [demo here](https://github.com/mfinkle/geckobrowser) and [Orfox here](https://github.com/guardianproject/Orfox) Basically, I can build the app which uses geckoview to render flash content on Android 4.1 but not 4.4 (Kitkat).

On Kikat it says

> Please install or enable Adobe Flash Player to view this content

There is a preference in firefox

```
PrefsHelper.setPref("plugin.disable", false);
```

this will toggle the flash plugin in firefox but that preference doesnt when I put it in Orfox.

I want to know which preference to enable flash on Geckoview? Or in general how to enable flash on geckoview android 4.4

I know flash is almost dead due to its poorly performance and support on mobile but there are still plenty of video contents are still in flash and we want to have flash support on our app

Some snippets and images in case you want to see

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGeckoView = (GeckoView) findViewById(R.id.gecko_view);

        mGeckoView.setChromeDelegate(new MyGeckoViewChrome());
        mGeckoView.setContentDelegate(new MyGeckoViewContent());
}
private class MyGeckoViewChrome extends GeckoViewChrome {
        @Override
        public void onReady(GeckoView view) {
                 PrefsHelper.setPref("javascript.enabled", true);
                 mGeckoView.addBrowser("http://www.dhs.state.il.us/accessibility/tests/flash/video.html");
        }
}
```

[image: Firefox and Orfox with GeckoView]

**Update 1:**
 After a day of digging into Firefox android source code, I think the question now is more like "How can we enabble plugin in GeckoView". I try to access "*`about:plugins`*" I see Flash hasnt been added while it has in 4.1 and Firefox(4.4). There is a method in `GeckoAppShell` thats locate flash library *`libflashplayer.so`* and it can actually find the lib. Not sure why it cant be loaded

Comment: Maybe you could pull libflashplayer.so out of Firefox for Android? Or maybe libflashplayer.so exists in source somewhere on Mozilla.

Comment: Anymore progress on this? I'd love to know. Thanks..

Comment: I failed to make GeckoView to work on March. I moved to another approach that use the whole firefox build to play flash

Comment: @CuongThai hello! Can you tell me, how you do that?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to run `flash file(swf)` in `GeckoView`. I am not sure how did you import the `jar` file in your project but follow the instructions to work it properly.

1. Download [geckoview_library](http://people.mozilla.org/~mfinkle/geckoview/geckoview_library.zip) and [assets](http://people.mozilla.org/~mfinkle/geckoview/geckoview_assets.zip)
2. Extract `geckoview_library.zip` and add the project as a lib project.
3. Extract `geckoview_assets.zip` and copy all the contents in your `project's assets` folder.

Now you can follow the example code [here](https://github.com/mfinkle/geckobrowser/blob/master/src/com/starkravingfinkle/geckobrowser/MainActivity.java).

**Note: You must have to install Adobe flash plugin for android. Install manually from [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installing-flash-player-android-devices.html)**